# Pulling SimpleXML Attributes with Namespaces

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I am attempting to display multiple records from a SOAP API. My call is working correctly and this is the XML response as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetDataResponse xmlns="urn:com:esi911:webeoc7:api:1.0">
            <GetDataResult>
                <data>
                    <record dataid="6" county="Fayette County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Inactive" />
                    <record dataid="5" county="Caldwell County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Inactive" />
                    <record dataid="4" county="Burnet County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Active" />
                    <record dataid="2" county="Blanco County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Active" />
                    <record dataid="1" county="Bastrop County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Active" />
                </data>
            </GetDataResult>
        </GetDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For now, I would just like to show the first of those records and its attributes on my webpage. I am throwing this response into SimpleXML and trying to grab those multiple attributes to display. Here is what I've attempted so far based on various other StackOverflow examples, but none really matched my exact XML response structure above either:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$response = $xml->xpath("//soap:Body/*")[0];
$result = $response->children("urn:com:esi911:webeoc7:api:1.0");
echo (string) $result->data->record[0]->attributes()->dataid;
```

I am not getting any specific errors ever. It's just always blank, nothing is displayed.

Eventually, I would need to loop through those records to display them all or store them into their own array for other uses later, but I cannot seem to even echo anything from the code above. I'm sure it has something to do with the multiple namespaces perhaps? Or just a basic typo somewhere?

Any advice with this XML response would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [register the namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) first and get the desired results with a single xpath query:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('urn', 'urn:com:esi911:webeoc7:api:1.0');
$records = $xml->xpath('//urn:record');

echo (string)$records[0]->attributes()->dataid;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/f8faC**

**Note**: you could be more accurate and use something like `//urn:GetDataResult/urn:data/urn:record` (instead of the shorter `//urn:record`) as the XPath query, in case there can be records at another place within the XML you receive.

Comment: This is definitely a more simple and condensed route to take. Thank you. I can get it working as you do in your demo with the XML response as a plain text variable. But, when I use it in my actual code, calling a live API, I still get nothing. The $xml object is empty even though the XML response is as I have provided above.

I am using cURL to get my XML response string and that is working as expected (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is TRUE). Anything else that might be causing this to work as a plain string, but not when coming from cURL?

Comment: If you echo the XML, is it exactly the same? There must be some kind of difference somewhere. Can you post some more details / explain what you're doing in your actual code (by editing your question)?

Comment: Best way to echo the returned XML?

Comment: @NetzzJD Just `echo` it and share the result. If it prints a string that is equal to the one you posted, the results shouldn't be different (other than character encoding stuff, but I doubt it would matter much in this case).

Comment: It is the same as originally shared. However, I have replaced the actual title and description attribute values here for obscurity. There are no special characters though. And I can take your demo link, replace the $xmlString with my real and actual XML in full and that code works. I can do the same in my own code if I copy/paste the echoed XML and wrap it within a normal, hard-coded variable instead of coming directly from the cURL response and this code works in that case as well. I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @NetzzJD What if you `var_dump` instead of `echo`. Anything out of the ordinary? Please post it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Using `echo`, `var_dump`, and `print_r` alone showed the same results. BUT, if I wrapped it in `htmlspecialchars()` I did finally spot a difference. Starting after the `<GetDataResult>` level the text is actually `&lt;data&gt;` instead of the expected `<data>` and `&lt;record dataid="6" county="Fayette County" title="Title goes here" description="Description goes here." status="Inactive" /&gt;`, etc. That would explain the empty result set after getting to that point. How would I handle this conversion now?

Comment: @NetzzJD Where are you checking the results of `htmlspecialchars`? On the actual output (command line or "view source" if it's on a webserver), or on the HTML page itself? If this is really what's returned by your cURL request, you could always call `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `html_entities_decode` before attempting to parse the DOM.

Comment: I was originally just outputting the XML in the browser on the HTML page itself and that's what I copied into my initial question as the response coming back, but the browser automatically converted and displayed the open/close tags for me which threw me off. Only when I output the XML response from the cURL request with `htmlspecialchars($response)` to the browser is when I see those literal characters were coming back from cURL. I've done exactly what you said with `$response=htmlspecialchars_decode($response);` before using that in my `simplexml_load_string` statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<GetDataResult>` element level, you fetch the `<soap:Body>` tag and then extract the children in the `"urn:com:esi911:webeoc7:api:1.0"` namespace - which will give you the `<GetDataResponse>` element, so...

```
echo (string) $result->GetDataResult->data->record[0]->attributes()->dataid;
```